# didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError is fired, how to get more info?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

For the first time I am  playing with APNS, I tried to run a proof of concept, with an iOS 5.0.1 device, and the `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` is fired. I know it has been fired because I show an `UIAlertView` to notify the error:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
   didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
   // Inform the user that registration failed
   NSString* failureMessage = @"There was an error while trying to \

     register for push notifications.";

   UIAlertView* failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                      message:failureMessage
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

   [failureAlert show];
   [failureAlert release];
}
```

How can I get more info about the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this code, which works and lets me progress a bit:

```
NSString* failureMessage = error.localizedDescription;    
UIAlertView* failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                 message:failureMessage
                                                 delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
[failureAlert show];
```

Sorry, iObjectiveC noob here.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like `NSLog(@"%@", error.userInfo");`, that should output some info into the terminal.